# Difference between multiprocessor and uniprocessor in terms of run-time system

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing

In the book "Advanced computer architecture and parallel processing" (El-Rewini & Abd-El-Barr), there is a question in the exercises of chapter 1 that needs the reader to compare between multiprocessor systems and uniprocessor systems in terms of many factors including run-time system:

> Compare uniprocessor systems with multiprocessor systems for the following aspects:
>
> 1. Ease of programming;
> 2. The need for synchronization;
> 3. Performance evaluation; and
> 4. Run-time system.

I know how to compare between these two systems in terms of the other factors (ease of programming, need for synchronization, and performance evaluation) but I can't to compare between them in terms of run-time system as I don't know what is the exact meaning of run-time system?

Comment: @D.W. Done editing.

Comment: @D.W. Edited. Please view it again. Thank you.

Comment: @greybeard Thank you very much .